# showing an inequality involving a random variable

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, both finite. IS it true that

$$ P\{\mu - d \sigma < X <\mu + d \sigma \} \geq 1 - \frac{1}{d^2} \text{ ??}  $$

Comment: Check Chebyshev‘s inequality

Comment: Hint: this is equivalent to $1 - P(|X-\mu| < d\sigma) \geq 1-\frac{1}{d^2}$. Use $P(|Y| \geq a) \leq \frac{E[Y]}{a}$ for a well-chosen $Y = f(X).

Answer (score 0):

This is Chebyshev's in equality.  Notice that it is equivalent to
$$
\Pr\left((X-\mu)^2 \le d^2 \sigma^2 \right) \ge 1 - \frac 1 {d^2}.
$$
Thus it follows from the proposition that for a non-negative-valued random variable $W$ with $\operatorname{E}(W)<\infty$, we have
$$
\Pr(W\le c\operatorname{E}(W)) \ge 1 - \frac 1 c,
$$
which is Markov's inequality.

To prove Markov's inequality, let $\displaystyle V=\left.\begin{cases} c\operatorname{E}(W) & \text{if }W\ge c\operatorname{E}(W), \\  0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}\right\}$  Then observe that $\operatorname{E}(V) = c\operatorname{E}(W)\Pr(W\ge c\operatorname{E}(W))$.  Since $V\le W$ and hence $\operatorname{E}(V)\le\operatorname{E}(W)$, this implies $\operatorname{E}(W)\ge c\operatorname{E}(W)\Pr(W\ge c\operatorname{E}(W))$, from which we finally get $\Pr(W\ge c\operatorname{E}(W))\le 1/c$.